# echo attributes from xml feed using simplexml

Tags: php, simplexml

Im new to simpleXML, so excuse me if this a very simple question, but I have been stuck on it for the past while.

I have the following xml structure

```
    <Export xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Random">
        <GeneralInformation></GeneralInformation>
        <Sport code="SOC" id="1" name="SOCCER">
            <Table leagueCode="22718">
                 <labels></labels>
                 <labels></labels>
                +<Team groupId="" id="2427"></Team>
                 <Team groupId="" id="11676">
                      <columns>
                           <column labelId="p" value="2"/>
                           <column labelId="tn" value="MANCHESTER CITY"/>
                           <column labelId="1" value="36"/>
                           <column labelId="2" value="22"/>
                           <column labelId="3" value="9"/>
                           <column labelId="4" value="5"/>
                           <column labelId="5" value="62"/>
                           <column labelId="6" value="31"/>
                           <column labelId="7" value="14"/>
                           <column labelId="8" value="3"/>
                           <column labelId="9" value="1"/>
                           <column labelId="10" value="39"/>
                           <column labelId="11" value="12"/>
                           <column labelId="12" value="8"/>
                           <column labelId="13" value="6"/>
                           <column labelId="14" value="4"/>
                           <column labelId="15" value="23"/>
                           <column labelId="16" value="19"/>
                           <column labelId="17" value="31"/>
                           <column labelId="18" value="0"/>
                           <column labelId="19" value="75"/>
                           <column labelId="st" value="Ch.Lg"/>\
                     </columns>
                   </Team>
                  +<Team groupId="" id="2420"></Team>
              </Table>
         </Sport>
     </Export>
```

In this example there are three teams (id=2427,11676,2420).

I would like to echo the 20 Value attribute for each team.

I have tried many different ways, using xpath, but i cant seem to echo anything. my latest code is something like this

```
$xml=  simplexml_load_file("$url") or die ("error: cannot creat object");

$list=$xml->xpath('/Export/Sport/Table/Team/columns');

foreach($list as $column){
     $value = $column['value'];
    echo $value;
    }
```

Any help would be great thanks.

p.s. This site is awesome

Comment: please post the full xml. not just the `Export` element

Comment: That is the full xml. It starts with <export>

Comment: are you getting any error messages?

Comment: No i dont get any error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath is selecting all the `columns` elements, not their children. So you need to either add `'/column'` on the end of your XPath expression, or have a nested loop (`foreach($list as $columns){ foreach($columns->column as $column) { ... } }`).

You are also trying to access the attribute `Value`, but the attribute in the XML you show is called `value`, with a lowercase 'v'.

Comment: I made the changes and still no luck, is it something to do the with noNamespaceSchemaLocation? The Other xml files work fine however this one requires a username and password in the url and its the only one not working.

Comment: just did a print_r and it is telling me IP-Access Denied, i will contact my xml provider. Thanks a ton